# In mongo aggregation pipeline, how to convert a field to array?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb 3.0.4. I have a collection of documents where site field is object. How can I convert this field to array?

```
{
  "_id": 123,
  "site": {"name": "a", "direction: "in"}
}
{
  "_id": 321,
  "site": [{"name": "a", "direction": "in"}]
}
```

Comment: You can use square brackets []  directly to create array if you can upgrade to 3.2.

Comment: You can add a $group by id  with push operator  in lower version to create an array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is $group the only way in mongodb 3.0.4. Using grouped by id is kind of sad...